# VS11 Dev Preview Unit Test Explorer doesn’t show Unit Tests

Tags: visual-studio, mstest

I wonder has anyone come across with this issue where the MSTest Unit Test doesn’t show up in the new Unit Test Explorer.

I’m running Windows 7 (32bit).  I downloaded the VS11 Developer Preview from the link below. http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27543

I created a sample C# Console App, and add the Test Library from the MSTest project template.  Then I created a sample Unit Test, and rebuild the solution.  When I open the Test Explorer (View->OtherWindows->UnitTest Explorer) I do not see any tests loaded.

I only see a message saying…
“No test discovered. Please build your project and ensure the appropriate test framework adapter is installed”.

I assume the MSTest adapter is automatically installed. If not I’m not even sure how to install an adapter.

I could be missing something here but I cannot figure it out. Has anyone experiencing this issue?

Comment: Btw. it is not VS 2011. It is VS 11.

Comment: Thanks, edited - sorry I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out that at this only works with Windows8. (At this stage)
More info
http://jerssoft.blogspot.com/2011/09/vs11-unit-test-explorer-acercamientos.html#more
 (you need to translate to English)

"*Of course, all this work the right way if we have properly configured and in the final version , since according to understand, if you want to try this plugin, you need to be working with Windows 8 :)* "

http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2011/09/24/running-unit-tests-in-visual-studio-2011-and-windows-8.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you are using VS Ultimate version of VS 11 developer preview, then it support MStest based unittesting for Windows7 style apps/projects if that is what you were trying out. It is possible that you are hitting a bug. Will it possible for you to share your repro steps?

Thanks,
Abhishek Agrawal
Program Manager, Visual Studio,
Microsoft Corp

Answer (score 1):

This wasn't working for me using Visual Studio Express 2012 Web RC, but I got it going eventually.

I added the reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework which I found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies

I made sure this was set to Copy Local but probably not required.

Then I tried cleaning and rebuilding but with no effect. I made sure I didn't have any testsettings selected (Test Menu > Test Settings > Untick the testrunconfig if selected), then changed my Test > Test Settings > Default Processor Architecture to x64 (my machine is x64).

Then I cleaned and rebuilt the solution and my Test Explorer was populated when I click Run All.